# Icon location problem with drawable Start in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have an editetext and I used drawable start, but the icon is not in the right place during execution

[Inside view of Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBmSp.jpg)

[Run the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0AkA.jpg)

First I put a scrollview, then a LinearLayout, inside it is a ConstraintLayout, then editText.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Activity.Activityy.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                    android:text="Hi Rechard"
                    android:textColor="#FF6D00"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="27dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:text="@string/order_eat"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="82dp"
                    android:layout_height="78dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/_f5736be590fe78e73bc4e4d7c012dda"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
                    android:layout_width="315dp"
                    android:layout_height="68dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/search_background"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/icons8_search_32"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Find Your Food"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Inside the execution, the texts have also moved to the right, while they are on the left side of the design.

Comment: Seems like the whole layout is flipped horizontally. Can you share the layout code

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal

Comment: Your entire layout is needed

Comment: The site gives an error and you say that the whole question is only code, what should I do to get it?

Comment: You need to add some more explaination

Comment: The entire code is needed as not only the edit text is flipped, but every other view is also flipped

Comment: Inside the execution, the texts have also moved to the right While they are on the left side of the design

Comment: that is exactly what i had told u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My phone's language is right, but my design is left, so when I run, it is automatically directed to the right
After a lot of research, I was able to solve my problem
Just go to the manifest file
And make the following line

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

To

```
android:supportsRtl="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

in android `start` means `left` and `end` means `right`

you must use `android:drawableEnd="ICON"` instead of `android:drawableStart="ICON"` to set icon right side.

Comment: that is exactly what he has done. He has used `android:drawableStart="@drawable/icons8_search_32"`

Comment: **Inside the execution, the texts have also moved to the right While they are on the left side of the design**